# Does conforming to Codable give me Core Data value transformation for free like conforming to NSCoding did?

Tags: swift, core-data, swift4

I am not very experienced with recent Core Data so please bear with me if I am missing important points here.

When conforming to NSCoding an NSObject didn't need to have it's own implementation of NSValueTransformer / ValueTransformer. You would describe it as Transformable in the Xcode model editor without defining a Value Transformer and the object would still persist as you would expect with the help of a NSValueTransfomer.

Now, Codable entered stage to replace NSCoding. The question is: does it already or will it give me the same convenience NSCoding gave me by not needing to implement a custom ValueTransformer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data doesn't know anything about `Codable`, so conforming to `Codable` makes no difference to how Core Data works. It would be really nice if what you described worked, and I suggest you [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple about it. I've already done so (rdar://37708071 in case anyone from Apple reads this), and the more people who ask, the more likely they'll add this.

For now, your options are:

- Keep using `NSCoding` and a transformable attribute.
- Use `Codable` but then convert to/from `Data` yourself outside of Core Data, and use a binary attribute.

Comment: Thank you, Tom. I was afraid it hasn't been implemented yet. I have added my suggestion (rdar://38295201)